# ООП: динамические массивы объектов

Tags: массивы, ооп, c++

Самостоятельно начал изучать ООП и с первого взгляда простое задание поставило меня в ступор. Помогите пожалуйста. Я создал класс. Хочу создать массив объектов данного класса и заполнить его не в мейне а в моем специальном методе put. После чего с помощью метода show вывести на экран. Память выделаю с помощью и освобождаю new deletе. Я тут что-то понаписывал, но оно все смешалось в фиг знает что и я уже ничего не соображаю. Покажите, пожалуйста, на простейшем примере как это реализовать, чтобы понять. Прошу прощения за эту порнографию вместо кода.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class cl
{
    public:
    int *mascl;

    cl(){}
    ~cl(){}
    void put(int *pm,int nm)
    {
        mascl = new int[nm];
        for(int i=0;i<nm;i++)
        {
            mascl[i]=3;
        }
        delete [] mascl;
    }
    void show()
    {

    }

};
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"set n"<<endl;//размер массива вводит юзер
    cin>>n;
    cl *pmas;
    pmas=new cl[n];
    put();//тут должно быть заполнение через функцию
    show();//тут должен быть вывод
    delete [] pmas;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: класс в своем методе должен заполнить массив объектов самого себя? (это можно решить с помощью статического метода, но думаю, оно пока не нужно).

Comment: Ну а как тогда заполнять массив объектов класса? Может я не понял как лучше это делать..

Comment: создайте себе отдельную функцию или даже отдельный класс для работы.

То есть, один класс хранит нужные данные, а другой класс хранит массив объектов предыдущего класса, а также функции с для заполнения/печати.

Comment: mascl = new int[nm];
    
и тут же
    
    delete [] mascl;

вы уверены, что это имеет смысл? А также наличие пустых конструктора и деструктора

Comment: в данном случае мне нечего написать в конструктор..я не знаю что тут удобно в него написать. Я его создал на всякий случай. А с делетом. я до этого думал сделать заполнение и вывод в одной функции..тогда бы оно удалило после вывода..а так как я их разделил не имеет.

Comment: в любом случае вам вряд ли стоило вызывать delete внутри этой функции. Освобождение ресурсов лучше поместить в деструктор, поскольку эти ресурсы могут пригодиться где-то еще, тогда как вы их уже освободили. То же самое касается выделения памяти с помощью new - это лучше бы сделать в конструкторе

Comment: можно пример какой-то...я понял общее назначение конструктора и деструктора..но они меня погают и как на практие их юзать я не знаю.

Comment: pmas=new cl[n];
    put();
    show();

put и show - это у вас должны быть отдельные ф-и или методы класса cl? А то я что-то не совсем понял из вашей ф-и main()

Comment: @BigBobo а можно у вас поинтересоваться, по каким источникам вы изучаете С++, что в них нет информации о применении конструкторов/деструкторов?

Comment: изначально я хотел чтобы это были методы класса cl. Но я не уверен что так можно делать.

Comment: немного не в тему, но, обязательно изучите [Code Style][1], чтобы не было cl, nm, pm


  [1]: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
cin>>n;
cl *pmas;
pmas=new cl[n];
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) // Заполнение массива объектов класса cl
{
    pmas[i].put(/*здесь нужные значения*/);
}
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) // Вызвать ф-ю show для каждого объекта cl в массиве
{
    pmas[i].show();
}
```

Ну и сам класс нужно переписать конечно. Так что лучше найдите какую-нибудб книжку по C++ для начинающих, так как судя по вашему коду, вы не понимаете даже самых элементарных принципов написания ООП кода. Могу посоветовать такую книгу для начинающих как Савич. Программирование на C++.